# Can't get data from mysql using a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I create a WP plugin , it is a form that user can submit some data. 
lets first look at the code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Plugin
Description: test plugin
Version: 4.0
Author: Hercal
License: GPL
*/
include('db.php'); //database connection file located in same folder .
?>

<?php function form_creation(){?> 
<form action=" <?php get_permalink(); ?> " method="post" id="myform">
<table>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="txtname" name="txtname" placeholder="Your Name"/> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<select id='select_Country' name="select_Country" >
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"> -- Select Country -- </option>
        <?php
        include(db.php);
        $query="select Code,Country from _Country order by Country";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<option value='.$row["Code"].'>'.$row["Country"].'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select> 

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>  <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit" name='submit'/> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php }?>

<?php
include(db.php);
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $name=strip_tags($_POST['txtname']);
    $country=$_POST['select_Country'];
$insertquery="insert into _customers(Name,Country)values('$name',(select Country from _country where Code = '$country')";
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$insertquery);
    if($query)
    {
        echo 'Data inserted successfully';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'there is a problem<br/>';
        print_r( (mysqli_errno($con)));
    }
}
?>
<?php add_shortcode('test', 'form_creation');?>
```

Now , when i use [test] shortcode and put it on my wordpress page , form loaded ,displayed but there is one problem .

1-Country field didn't load from database , so the drop down load with only one choice 
,Select Country

keep in mind : 
1-when I Enter a name and press submit , name inserted successfully to DB which means that db.php has no problem , so why the select country query didn't return values.

2-when i run the same code on root(without WP) , it works fine and country loaded successfully but when i call this plugin from WordPress using ShortCode , problem happens

I need your support , thanks .

Comment: why you are doing like this? why not using the inbuilt function by wordpress? Use global $wpdb to access the wordpress queries, Dig this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: @jogesh_pi  thanks , i read it now , but why the above code not working ?

Comment: is it possible that include(db.php) works when you run without WP, but when you load in WP context the working directory is different, so you need a relative path as in `include(./db.php)' or similar? This has happened to me...

Comment: @Robp but the insert query worked fine using db.php

Comment: yes, but is the include(db.php) above actually working, or failing to find that file to include it?

Comment: you asked me ? , i have the problem , i should ask :D 

look @Robp , now it is working fine after using $wpdb but i hope to know why include(db.php) worked with insert and didn't work with select ,.....may be because the select query was inside function , just guessing ..

Comment: table names are case-sensitive! you call the table '_country' for the insert but '_Country' for the select!

Comment: @robp , u speaks about this line --[$insertquery="insert into _customers(Name,Country)values('$name',(select Country from _country where Code = '$country')";]-- this line works fine , the main problem in --[ $query="select Code,Country from _Country order by Country";]--which exist in select_country dropdown menu

Comment: do you notice how the table name is "_country" in the one that works and "_Country" in the one that doesn't? the capital C must be a typo.

Comment: No , it is not case sensitive , both c or C are not work , for the working one , i test to change the letter state from small to capital or from capital to small , it works normal .

Comment: use mysqli_connect_error() to find the last error, what is in the $result variable?

Comment: @Hercal2020 is the db.php connecting to the same database as Wordpress? If so, the code you have there is wrong.

Comment: @david ok , i will try it and feed u back